# Basic React code not producing any output

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I just started with React and wrote my very first code but as per the video(tutorial) the output is not generated.

```js
function People(prop){
  return(
    <div className="peer">
  <h1>{prop.nam}</h1>
  <h3>age: {prop.age}</h3>
 
</div>
   
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<peer name="Mark" age="20"/>,document.querySelector("#p1"));
```

```css
.peer{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px blue;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="p1"></div>
```

Comment: Your function is called People not Peer.

Comment: and `<h1>{prop.name}</h1>` instead of `<h1>{prop.nam}</h1>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing your `People` component correctly in your render call. It should look something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<People name="Mark" age="20"/>, document.querySelector("#p1"));
```

**Also Worth Noting:** Stylistically you should name your `prop` parameter `props`. This and you're also missing an *e* to your *name* prop.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve to use PascalCase name for react components. so instead of using `<peers ... />` , which i think is undefined in your case, use `<People ... />`, which is actually there in your component file.